# Re-import packages in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I'm aware of options to re-import data to tables using table_exists_action and can give options like skip,append or replace for the data.

But is there an option to re-import packages (re-create) into the database if they are already existing without throwing up an error like

" Package PKG_1 already exists"

I basically have packages which have some changes in them and re-import to another environment where there packages are already existing.

Comment: What import tool are you using?  Please show relevant details, like the command line parameters, etc.

Comment: standard oracle impdp command
    os : aix
    database: oracle 11g R2

    impdp userid/pwd@inst1 directory=dir1

Comment: That is strange, because I think it should just overwrite the package.  I don't think there is a specific option.  Maybe try on dba.stackexchange.

Comment: I don't believe there is any way to get impdp to replace existing packages; you'll need to drop the existing objects before running the import.